# Ubercart for drupal, how to add customer ID (identification) field?

Tags: drupal, field, cck, ubercart

I want to ask for the customer to enter his ID when he buys something.
Is it hard to add a new field apart from the default: name, phone, address etc ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Ubercart doesn't use Drupal's Form API, so a simple [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) won't work. However, [here is a blog post with one potential option](http://civicactions.com/blog/2009/nov/03/ubercart_modifying_checkout_panes). The [Extra Fields Checkout Pane](http://www.ubercart.org/project/uc_extra_fields_pane) may also be worth looking into.

Comment: p.s. - You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers Beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: I've put the same question there as well, still no luck.